# Каким образом данные пришедшие из Facebook JavaScript SDK засунуть в базу?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api, php, mysql

Добрый вечер.
Я вот уже какой день пытаюсь разобраться с Facebook api.
По ихнему мануалу мне разобраться трудно, так что я взял для примера [реализацию некоего Махмуда Ахсана](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/), здесь можно посмотреть пример как это у него работает [здесь](http://thinkdiff.net/demo/newfbconnect1/jssdkouth2.html), а также исходники на [гитхабе](https://github.com/mahmudahsan/New-JavaScript-SDK---OAuth-2.0-based-FBConnect-Tutorial/blob/master/jssdkouth2.html).

Так вот, у меня есть сайт, на сайте есть кнопка авторизации с фейсбука, при клике на нее появляется всплывающее окно и юзеру предлагается принять 'соглашение' приложения. После того как он согласился, на сайт в javascript приходит его данные.
В таком вот виде мы можем их ловить.

```
function login(response, info){
if (response.authResponse) {
    var accessToken=response.authResponse.accessToken;
    userInfo.innerHTML=info.name        //имяпользователя
              +"<br/>"+info.gender          //пол пользователя
              +"<br/>"+info.locale        //его локализация
              +"<br />Your Access Token: "+accessToken;
    }
}
```

Т.е. данные мы получили, а как их в базу засунуть? Чтобы при следующем заходе на сайт, юзер уже был авторизирован. Или это можно сделать только если работать через PHP SDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После того как пришли данные от OpenID провайдера, нужно передать данные от OpenID скрипту на сервере, который проверяет- если пользователя не существует, то проводит регистрацию, если существует, то авторизует.

Comment: ну вот этот кусок кода что я дал - это уже и есть на моем сайте. Вопрос вот в чем: "передать данные от OpenID скрипту, который проверяет- если пользователя не существует" - какому скрипту передать? Всмысле.. нельзя же из javascript в базу запросы делать) каким образом из javascript в php обратиться? Через ajax?

Comment: Любым удобным способом. ajax, location.href, jQuery. Способ не имеет значения, главное передать данные на сервер.

Comment: Из того что приходит на ум, схема такая:  
пользователь авторизируется по кнопке, мы получаем все основные данные профиля, передаём все эти данные ajax'ом на сервер, там проверяем по базе есть ли уже юзер с таким айдишником (айдишник юзера в фейсбуке), если нету то заносим все эти данные в базу, а если есть - просто игнорируем. так получается?

Comment: если есть, то не игнорируем, а авторизуем на своем сайте.

Comment: а что вы подразумеваете под авторизируем?  
поставить куки чтоли? и с чем же, что в них засовывать то? или сессию?